# Voice Dialling opening on lock screen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, phone-app, voice-command, motorola-moto-g

I've got a Moto G running KitKat and am having an issue where the Voice Dialler (I think that's what it's called) opens up when the phone is in my pocket, locked.

I have no idea how it is happening.. I presume there is some combination of buttons you can press to open it, and these are getting pressed in my pocket. I regularly have headphones plugged in to the phone, so it is perhaps related to that.

My question is, how is this Voice Dialler app opening and how can I disable it? I haven't installed any third party app so I presume it's a part of Google Now, or some Motorola app that came with the phone...?

I haven't been able to get a screenshot, but the app opens and a voice prompts me to say a name or phone number to dial.. Very annoying as it cuts off Spotify and I have to unlock the phone and hit the play button again.

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty useless app if you don't use it (forever). So what you can do is **disable it**. Go through `Settings>Apps/App Manager>All>Voice Dialler>Disable`. Thats it. You can enable it again if you wish when needed.